# XML: Searching, if node value found return a different node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

not sure if the title is right but ... im trying to search a XML for a node and if it's there return a different node.

here is what im working with c# code;

```
allianceN.Text = new XElement("eveapi", (from c in dataElements.Elements("result") select new XElement("result", c.Element("factionID"))).Take(1)).Value;
```

This returns the value of: 61000575 i want to then use this to search this XML: `https://api.eveonline.com/eve/ConquerableStationList.xml.aspx`

and return the node (stationName) value of:

> 6-8QLA V - Learning Isn't Free

forgot to add the code im trying to work with:

```
XmlDocument xxdocoA = new XmlDocument();
xxdocoA.Load(StationListAA);
 XmlNodeList xnodeA = xxdocoA.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/row[@allianceN]");
                    foreach(XmlNode xnodA in xnodeA)
                    {
                        string NameN = xnodA.Attributes["stationName"].InnerText;
                    }
```

Sample XML where i get my StationID value:

```
    <eveapi version="2"><currentTime>2016-02-05 09:35:05</currentTime><result><characterID></characterID>
<name></name>
<homeStationID>61000575</homeStationID>
<DoB></DoB>
<race></race>
<bloodLineID></bloodLineID>
<bloodLine></bloodLine>
<ancestryID></ancestryID>
<ancestry></ancestry>
<gender></gender>
<corporationName></corporationName>
<corporationID></corporationID>
<allianceName></allianceName>
<allianceID></allianceID>
<factionName/></result></eveapi>
```

Exmaple of station names:

```
    <eveapi version="2"><currentTime>2016-02-05 08:24:56</currentTime><result>
<rowset name="outposts" key="stationID" columns="stationID,stationName,stationTypeID,solarSystemID,corporationID,corporationName,x,y,z">
<row stationID="61001046" stationName="W-XY4J X - HAKOHELITO" stationTypeID="21646" solarSystemID="30001105" corporationID="98021158" corporationName="corporation federal agents space" x="394820444160" y="-18220769280" z="-6131542302720"/>
<row stationID="61001047" stationName="7MD-S1 XI - Roland's Place" stationTypeID="21645" solarSystemID="30001232" corporationID="98132485" corporationName="Bailiffs" x="-2950319185920" y="-500139909120" z="2101918064640"/>
<row stationID="61001048" stationName="E9KD-N IX - RIP Vile Rat" stationTypeID="21645" solarSystemID="30003694" corporationID="418183520" corporationName="EXPCS Corp" x="1474703155200" y="-198735421440" z="450142740480"/>
<row stationID="61001049" stationName="27-HP0 VI - Brasil TEC Aerospace" stationTypeID="21644" solarSystemID="30000832" corporationID="478292232" corporationName="Brasil TEC" x="785816985600" y="4615004160" z="-576230154240"/>
<row stationID="61001050" stationName="L-5JCJ VIII - RUSTARPORT" stationTypeID="21645" solarSystemID="30002142" corporationID="98139285" corporationName="Love All Woodland Nymphs" x="-2645266391040" y="533918883840" z="-6264785510400"/>
<row stationID="61001051" stationName="Y5-E1U VII - The Dibby Parlour" stationTypeID="21646" solarSystemID="30000729" corporationID="98415166" corporationName="Zero.Four Holdings" x="-1276127109120" y="32335749120" z="4544564551680"/>
<row stationID="61001052" stationName="F2-NXA II - The Valley of Eternal Night" stationTypeID="21645" solarSystemID="30000695" corporationID="98025393" corporationName="Fleet of the Eternal Night" x="-47411404800" y="7704944640" z="139655454720"/>
<row stationID="61001053" stationName="3-SFWG V - DRASY Jobcenter" stationTypeID="21644" solarSystemID="30001212" corporationID="98278570" corporationName="Das Raumfahrer Syndikat" x="922842685440" y="85610864640" z="-2470096035840"/>
<row stationID="61001054" stationName="UQ-PWD III - Home of the Demon Clown Legion" stationTypeID="21646" solarSystemID="30001208" corporationID="261632485" corporationName="Fink Operations" x="-49921351680" y="4879687680" z="-123196661760"/>
<row stationID="61001055" stationName="1EO-OE V - Traffic island" stationTypeID="21646" solarSystemID="30003211" corporationID="98064360" corporationName="Despair fellow pilots" x="-1619052011520" y="28839813120" z="84353310720"/>
<row stationID="61001056" stationName="G-4H4C III - Kazeboshka" stationTypeID="21646" solarSystemID="30003161" corporationID="98396853" corporationName="Lavina Holding" x="-54066094080" y="3877724160" z="146350448640"/>
<row stationID="61001057" stationName="G7AQ-7 VIII - Providence STD Clinic" stationTypeID="21644" solarSystemID="30003713" corporationID="101116365" corporationName="W.A.S.P" x="1285768519680" y="-36475576320" z="-3470034739200"/>
<row stationID="61001058" stationName="FA-DMO X - VOTE THE JUDGE FOR C S M XI" stationTypeID="21646" solarSystemID="30000233" corporationID="1667598016" corporationName="SRBI Holding" x="-1172241408000" y="235930214400" z="326454435840"/></result></eveapi>
```

These files are big so this is just a snippet of what it looks like and sorry if the closing tags are wrong.

Comment: Add sample of xml file.

Comment: Hope this helps i did add the link to the XML if it helps more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know it's bad to answer my own question however just incase someone else needs this kind of info here is how i did it:

```
string string1 = new XElement("eveapi", (from c in dataElements.Elements("result") select new XElement("result", c.Element("homeStationID"))).Take(1)).Value;

 XmlDocument STIDD = new XmlDocument();
                        STIDD.Load(StationListAA);
                        XmlNodeList xnodeAA = STIDD.SelectNodes("eveapi/result/rowset/row[@stationID =" + string1 + "]");
                        foreach(XmlNode xxnodAA in xnodeAA)
                        {
                            allianceN.Text = xxnodAA.Attributes["stationName"].InnerText;
                        }
```

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So you have "61000575" and want the stationName of the node that has stationID="61000575".

That would be either `//row[@stationID='61000575']/@stationName` or:

```
(new XDocument(...)).Root.Descendants("row").Where(row=>row.Attribute("stationID").Value == "61000575").Single().Attribute("stationName")
```

Comment: the problem is this stationID can change. it currently takes the stationID number i've given to you from another XML

Comment: Umm... just replace the literal ("61000575") with a variable?

Comment: can you give me an example of how i might do this / what it looks like, i've tried converting the first part into a string to try and use that to search but it's not working still.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication75
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml1 = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                    "<Root>" +
                      "<eveapi version=\"2\">" +
                        "<currentTime>2016-02-05 09:35:05</currentTime>" +
                        "<result>" +
                          "<characterID></characterID>" +
                          "<name></name>" +
                          "<homeStationID>61001046</homeStationID>" +
                          "<homeStationID>61001047</homeStationID>" +
                          "<DoB></DoB>" +
                        "</result>" +
                      "</eveapi>" +
                    "</Root>";

            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(xml1);
            string[] stationIDs = doc1.Descendants("homeStationID").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

            string xml2 =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                  "<eveapi version=\"2\">" +
                    "<currentTime>2016-02-05 08:24:56</currentTime>" +
                    "<result>" +
                      "<rowset name=\"outposts\" key=\"stationID\" columns=\"stationID,stationName,stationTypeID,solarSystemID,corporationID,corporationName,x,y,z\">" +
                        "<row stationID=\"61001046\" stationName=\"W-XY4J X - HAKOHELITO\" stationTypeID=\"21646\" solarSystemID=\"30001105\" corporationID=\"98021158\" corporationName=\"corporation federal agents space\" x=\"394820444160\" y=\"-18220769280\" z=\"-6131542302720\"/>" +
                        "<row stationID=\"61001047\" stationName=\"7MD-S1 XI - Roland's Place\" stationTypeID=\"21645\" solarSystemID=\"30001232\" corporationID=\"98132485\" corporationName=\"Bailiffs\" x=\"-2950319185920\" y=\"-500139909120\" z=\"2101918064640\"/>" +
                        "<row stationID=\"61001048\" stationName=\"E9KD-N IX - RIP Vile Rat\" stationTypeID=\"21645\" solarSystemID=\"30003694\" corporationID=\"418183520\" corporationName=\"EXPCS Corp\" x=\"1474703155200\" y=\"-198735421440\" z=\"450142740480\"/>" +
                       "</rowset>" +
                    "</result>" +
                  "</eveapi>";

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml2);
            XElement[] stationIDsNodes = stationIDs.Select(x => doc2.Descendants("row").Where(y => y.Attribute("stationID").Value == x)).SelectMany(z => z).ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```